# Bull queue - Queue was working fine but suddenly, stops working

Tags: node.js, redis, queue, bull, bull-queue

I have implemented bull queue. It was working fine but now, queue stops working. I checked redis server. These keys are present -

```
1) "bull:<queue_name>:stalled-check"
2) "bull:<queue_name>:id"
3) "bull:<queue_name>:lock"
4) "bull:<queue_name>"
5) "bull:<queue_name>:stalled-check"
6) "bull:<queue_name>:active"
```

I am unable to figure out what wrong has happened. Please help in this.

Comment: Please be more specific. How exactly has the queue stopped working?

Comment: Probably it is a duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504093/jobs-stuck-in-waiting-in-bull-queue-node-js ?